# Windows 8 phone System.StackOverflowException while filling a listbox using class system

Tags: c#, list, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have the error System.StackOverflowException, everytime I run my app. This error is located in the last line of my History class. Below:

```
public class userHistory
{
    public string strTimeDate { get; set; }
    public string strUrl { get; set; }

    public List<userHistory> lstUserHistory { get; set; }

    public userHistory(string timedate, string url)
    {
        lstUserHistory.Add(new userHistory(timedate, url));
    }
}
```

My MainPage code:

```
 public List<userHistory> lstUserHistory;
    public userHistory selectedHistory;


public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox.DataContext = lstUserHistory;
    }

private void getHistory(string url)
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        userHistory usrHistory = new userHistory(time, url);
        lstUserHistory.Add(usrHistory);

        listBox.DataContext = null;
        listBox.DataContext = lstUserHistory;
    }

    private void listBox_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedHistory = listBox.SelectedValue as userHistory;

        MessageBox.Show(selectedHistory.strUrl);
        browserSearch(selectedHistory.strUrl);
    }
```

The XAML

```
  <Grid>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" Foreground="RoyalBlue" Name="listBox" TabIndex="10"  Tap="listBox_Tap">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,329,0,367" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding strDateTime}" FontSize="15" Margin="51,1,0,1"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding strUrl}" FontSize="28" Margin="51,1,0,1"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </Grid>
```

I think the error might be because of what happens in getHistory. This method can be called muitply times with the same data. All I would like is for the data to be stored in a List, which can easily add new history records, or remove them. Then be displayed simply in a List box.

Thank you in advance :)

If you need any more details please comment and I will be happy to explain in further detail :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this part of `userHistory`:

```
public List<userHistory> lstUserHistory { get; set; }

public userHistory(string timedate, string url)
{
    lstUserHistory.Add(new userHistory(timedate, url));
}
```

There are two bugs here:

- The constructor calls itself (boom! stack overflow)
- The constructor calls `lstUserHistory.Add` when `lstUserHistory` is definitely null

It's not clear why you've got a `List<userHistory>` in both your MainPage code *and* in `userHistory`. I think you need to think more carefully about the data you're modelling, and what *really* belongs where.

I suspect your `userHistory` class should actually look more like this:

```
public sealed class HistoryEntry
{
    private readonly DateTime timestamp;
    private readonly string url;

    public DateTime Timestamp { get { return timestamp; } }
    public string Url { get { return url; } }

    public HistoryEntry(DateTime timestamp, string url)
    {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Unless you really *need* the class to be mutable, make it immutable
- Follow .NET naming conventions
- Avoid name prefixes which just specify the type
- Use the appropriate data type to model what you're interested in - a date/time *isn't* naturally a string
- Decide what the role of this class is - is it an entry, or the whole history? With my changes, it's clear that this is just an entry. If you need to model the whole history as a separate class, do that as well, rather than trying to combine the two.

Comment: @user3795349: Well yes, I've suggested renaming the `userHistory` type to `HistoryEntry` for starters. If this sort of thing is giving you issues, it sounds like you may be very new to C# development. If that's the case, I'd strongly advise you to put this project aside for a while, and learn the *basics* of C# in a simpler environment, experimenting with console applications until you're really comfortable with how the language and some core aspects of the framework (collections, IO etc) work. It'll make it much easier to make progress on your real application.

Comment: Thank you, I have been learning c# for while and I find I learn best through tough projects like this. The moment I wrote that comment I then realised that I needed to rename it, all the errors have gone but while running the app it crashes and goes to the app.xaml.cs and breaks on the last line of the Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) method. Thank you

Comment: @user3795349: Well then I suggest you look at what that exception is, and go from there. Learning to diagnose errors is a vital part of learning to code.

Comment: In the output console the two errors are "A first chance exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'" occurred and 
"A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred" just before the app closed. There is no other error help, where do I go from here in debugging.

Comment: @user3795349: You launch it in a debugger, and put a breakpoint in `Application_UnhandledException`, to start with - and look at the stack trace. But a Stack Overflow comment thread really isn't the right place to learn debugging...